# can this code be shortened or improved?

Tags: python, passwords

Can this be shortened/improved? I'm trying to make a password checker in python.

Could the if's be put into a for loop? And if so, how?

```
pw = input("Enter password to test: ")

caps = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isupper())
lower = sum(1 for c in pw if c.islower())
nums = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isnumeric())

scr = ['weak', 'medium', 'strong']
r = [caps, lower, nums]


if len(pw) < 6:
    print("too short") 
elif len(pw) > 12:
    print("too long")

if caps >= 1:
    if lower >= 1:
        if nums >= 1:
            print(scr[2])
        elif nums < 1:
            print("your password is " + scr[1])
    elif lower < 1:
        print("your password strength is " + scr[0])
elif caps < 1:
    print("your password strength is " + scr[1])
```

Thanks for any suggestions :D

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is where this should be.  the answer to both questions Im sure is yes, it can be both shortened and improved

Comment: The `scr[1]` is definitely not simpler or more meaningful than `'medium'`. (And if you're looking to make your strings localizable… there are better ways to do that.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing working code. Try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: @abarnert: I suspect we have differing views on what constitutes "working code" :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Well, he's assuming his code is correct and just asking us to simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

```
caps = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isupper())
```

can be:

```
caps = sum(c.isupper() for c in pw)
```

---

```
if caps >= 1:
```

can be:

```
if caps:
```

---

The most *significant* improvement: The bottom `if`/`elif` block can be completely removed by doing

```
i_strength = sum(map(bool,[caps,lower,nums])) - 1 #or sum(map(bool,r)) - 1
print('your password is {}'.format(scr[i_strength]))
```

Explanation: `map(bool,[caps,lower,nums])` accumulates how many times each of `caps,lower,nums` is non-zero.  Adding them up with `sum` gives you your "strength", which you've conveniently already put into a list, which can be accessed by index.

All of these improvements leverage the concept of "falsiness" in python, otherwise known as an object's value in a boolean context.  Generally empty and zero things are `False`, and summing booleans is equivalent to adding ones and zeroes, so there you go.

---

Of course, it doesn't seem that you're *doing* anything with the counts of upper/lower/nums other than checking if they're nonzero.  So a cleanup would just be

```
caps = any(c.isupper() for c in pw)
...
```

and then

```
i_strength = sum([caps,lower,nums]) -1
```

Comment: ...and like this the password strength check makes a bit more sense. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

I would fix that nested if statement.

```
scr = ['weak', 'medium', 'strong'] # if you want to keep this fine
# but I suggest you do something like this:
_WEAK = scr[0] 
_MEDIUM = scr[1]
_STRONG = scr[2]
if caps >= 1 and lower >= 1 and nums >= 1:
   print(_STRONG)
elif caps < 1:
    print("your password strength is " + _MEDIUM)
elif lower < 1:
   print("your password strength is " + _WEAK)
elif nums < 1:
   print("your password is " + _MEDIUM)
```

Comment: But that's a different logic. Not that the OP's logic made any sense, but this doesn't either.

Answer (score 0):

I'll ignore the general question, "can this code be shortened or improved", because that's a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). But you've also got a specific question in there:

> Could the if's be put into a for loop? And if so, how?

They could, but you'd have to turn them into something that can be put inside an iterator, like functions, and I really don't think you want to in this case.

Let's start with a simpler example, with just a linear series of checks:

```
checks = [
    ((lambda caps, lower, num: caps >= 1 and lower >= 1 and nums >= 1), 2),
    ((lambda caps, lower, num: caps < 1), 1),
    ((lambda caps, lower, num: lower < 1), 0),
    ((lambda caps, lower, num: num < 1), 1)
]
for check, value in checks:
    if check(caps, lower, num):
        print('your password strength is ' + scr[value])
        break
```

You could instead put the check conditions in some encoded data form, and replace the `if check(…)` with a data-driven check on the conditions. For example:

```
checks = [
    ((1, 1, 1), 2),
    ((-1, 0, 0), 1),
    ((0, -1, 0), 0),
    ((0, 0, -1), 1)
]
for check, value in checks:
    for value, condition in zip((caps, lower, num), check):
        if condition == -1 and value >= 1 or condition == 1 and value < 1:
            break
    else:
        print('your password strength is ' + scr[value])
        break
```

But I think that's even less readable. There are plenty of use cases where this kind of thing makes sense—e.g., imagine you wanted to evaluate 40 polynomials for each value of x; you'd store each polynomial as a list of coefficients, and have generic "evaluate polynomial" logic like this. But this isn't one of those cases.

Either way, that's already pretty ugly. And if you want nested checks, you're going to need a nested structure, which you probably want to process recursively.